# Navigation based Application and UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am creating a navigation based application and in the root view, it lists an array of choices, which as many you know leads to a more specific choice. My question is the lists that is displayed on the root view is actually not a choices of different functionality like calendar,mail but a choice, which is going to do the same functionality with different values.So I am wondering whether I should create a different view controller for each of the choices or I should just update the existing view. Which one is more efficient. Choice of inputs comes from a dictionary. I really appreciate your inputs. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I **assume** that you want to have a screen with a number of "settings". Clicking on one of the settings will slide in a new view where the user can pick between a number of options. So basically you have two views each with a table and a navigation controller on top, right?

If this assumption is right, then **I propose the following**:

Create one view controller for the "front view".
This view controller will display the different "settings" and know that selecting one of the settings should slide in the next view.

This next view should be handled by a second view controller. It sounds like the different settings can be handled by one view controller.

**So basically: Two view controllers, one for the first "level" and a different one for the second "level".**

Comment: Hey Thanks, That answers my question perfectly.I have more than 3 levels of hierarchy and multiple settings, so do you think (number of settings)*(levels of hierarchy) view controllers, the most efficient way to create this kind of application.

Comment: Well, if the settings are not too different, i.e. pick some text from a list, then you can use the same ViewController for all the settings.
But if they are very different, i.e. one needs a picker, another is a slider, then have one view controller for each setting.